# Deadlock in Tomcat server running on Eclipse within Logging

Tags: java, eclipse, jquery, tomcat

I'm running repeatedly into deadlock issues on Tomcat in Eclipse. I'm calling JAX-RS services from a Chrome browser from a JSP page using JQuery.ajax calls (although I'm not sure the calling mechanism is really an issue other than being multiple async calls occurring simultaneously). The exception may be dynatree; it seems to have gotten worse after setting up lazy load of a dynatree file tree.

When it fails I see multiple ajax calls all pending.

If I debug in Eclipse, open the server, and pause, I see:

```
Daemon Thread [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (Suspended)
 owns: WebappClassLoader (id=53)
 waiting for: FileHandler (id=50)
   owned by: Daemon Thread [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (Suspended)
  FileHandler.publish(LogRecord)
  Logger.log(LogRecord)
  Logger.doLog(LogRecord)

Daemon Thread [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (Suspended)
 owns: FileHandler (id=50)
 waiting for: WebappClassLoader (id=53)
   owned by: Daemon Thread [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (Suspended)
  RequestScope$Instance.toString() line: 531
  MessageFormat.subformat(...)
  MessageFormat.format(...)
  ...
  SimpleFormatter...
  FileHandler(StreamHandler).publish(LogRecord)
  FileHandler.publish(LogRecord)
  Logger.log(LogRecord)
```

So very much seems to be a deadlock, all within logging to some extent or other. But I've no idea why this occurs or what to do about it. Internally I'm just using java.util.logging.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I should also note that this appears to occur entirely outside of my own code. The remainder of either stack trace contain only system code, nothing of mine. I've also debugged into the methods that get called and they run and return as normal.

Comment: Given additional investigation, it appears that this is actually a problem with the Derby database driver, possibly a known bug. In some cases it hangs trying to create a database statement.

Answer (score 0):

Given additional investigation, it appears that this is actually a problem with the Derby database driver, possibly a known bug. In some cases it hangs trying to create a database statement.